# The vb.net code stucks at While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete

Tags: vb.net

I am developing an application in vb.net which fetches some information from the system and then update the details collected to a ready made webpage. I am using the InternetExplorer object for the same. Please find the code below.

```
Dim WebBrowser1 As Object = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

`Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)`
     Handles Button1.Click

```
WebBrowser1.Visible = True

 WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://abcd.com/webform1.aspx")

    While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While


WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("infoUserName").InnerText = EndUserName
```

Here the While condition generates an exception and says that 
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. `(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED))`

Comment: It might be this bug: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/924432 or something solved by this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cdd671c4-bcc5-441a-8569-122947fd54ed/rpcedisconnected-when-automatiing-internet-explorer-to-navigate-to-an-xml-file-with-no-admin-priv?forum=vclanguage

Comment: You are asking for this kind of trouble, avoid DoEvents like the plague.  Move the code that's after this loop into the event handler for the DocumentCompleted event

Comment: @HansPassant Hi Hans, Thanks for the reply. But here the issue is I have declared WebBrowser1 as Internet Explorer object. So When I use the DocumentCompleted event, it is giving error as This vent is not part of object. Can you help me on this

Comment: Hi All, I have resolved the issue. The url https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806858/rpc-e-disconnected-when-automatiing-internet-explorer-to-navigate-to-an-html-or-xml-file-with-no-admin-priv explains it more. I have enabled protected mode in IE and it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. The url connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806858/… explains it more. I have enabled protected mode in IE and it started working fine